# Blank pokestop / gym photo disc issue

Tags: pokemon-go

So today I went to the neighboring town for some  needs there I saw a pokestop and another gym which had blank photo discs

[image]

[image]

These pokestop and gym are new, these weren't there a month before , and I didn't nominate it.

What makes it happen so? I have created 2 stops and a gym in my town, all containing proper photo disc !

Comment: This is common if the game didn't download the image yet (e.g. because the internet connection is somewhat bad over there).

Comment: @Sumurai , even after an hour or two, it remains same, I don't think it's network problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On May 5 2021, Niantic did a batch import of new waypoints from some third-party database. This import was not done correctly, and included a large number of waypoints that did not meet quality standards, which among other things included many not having a photo attached.

You can read more information about this [here](https://community.wayfarer.nianticlabs.com/discussion/16876/an-update-on-newly-added-wayspots).

Comment: thanks this solved my doubt

Comment: Can I add a photo to the pokestop and gym? I doubt because they are third party assets .

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar Typically waypoints added from third-party databases allow for adding photos and editing the title/description unless they're part of a sponsor deal, which these are presumably not. So you should be able to add a photo.

Comment: Thank you so much